# Split/group array elements by field

Tags: php, arrays, split, grouping

For a game, I have a collection of 'houses' and each house belongs to a 'city'. I want to separate this collection (it's an array) based on this city, so each city will have its own array of houses. I found no built-in array function to do this (such as an `array_split` taking a callback), so how would I do this?

I thought on iterating over every element of the array, but this seems very very slow. The houses are already all ordered by city id, so I may use some splitting function if I get the exact position where the city id changes.

Houses in the array are stored like this:

```
array(3) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1",
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Example House",
    ["city_id"]=> string(1) "1",
}
```

Cities are just a number representing them, not another object.

I expect the out to be something like:

```
array(n) {
    [1]=> array(o) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1",
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Example House",
    }, ...
}
```

Is it the correct manner to do it? Is there any builtin function or better algorithm?

Comment: How are they (_houses and city_) mapped ? Can you show your sample array ?

Comment: It would be much easier for us to understand by looking at your array format and the code associate with it rather than the explanation, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added an output of `print_r` with an example.

Comment: Take a look at usort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: So how do you want the expected output to be ? Sorry still unclear though..

Comment: @DamienOvereem, OP said they are already organized.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran updated, I explained how I expect the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to work on your structure without looping it.. Maybe you can simplify it like this..

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $arr1)
{
    $new_arr[$arr1['id']] = array_slice($arr1,1);
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/144866)</kbd>

Eventhough this can be achieved using array functions , but performance will not be that good when compared to a `foreach`